# Nothing display after a form and can't see the source code using browser

Tags: php, html

I'm trying with 2 php code to ask to the user his username and his password.
And then to display : "You're  authorised" if his password match with the string "coco" and display "You're not authorised if it doesn't match.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method="post" action="secret.php">
            <label for="identifiant">Identifiant: </label>
                <input type="text" name="identifiant" id="identifiant" placeholder="identifiant" size="20" maxlength="20"/>
            <label for="password">Mot de passe: </label>
                <input type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="password" size ="20" maxlength="20"/>
        </form> 
        <input type="submit" value="Valider"/>
    </body>
</html>
```

And the second php code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
            if (!(isset($_POST['identifiant'])))
                echo "missing identifiant"; <br />
            if (isset($_POST['password']))
            {
                if (strcmp($_POST['password'], "coco") == 0)
                    echo "You're authorised";
                else
                    echo "You're not authorised";
            }
            else
                echo "missing password";
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Anyone have an idea ?

Thank's
Kind Regards

Comment: Your code is not complete.

Comment: where is the secret.php?

Comment: Sorry, there was a trouble when I send it to the site.
I modified my post :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your secret.php try to replace this

```
echo "missing identifiant"; <br />
```

by:

```
echo "missing identifiant<br />";
```

Comment: Thank you so much !
It's work ! But how the behavior can be completely different when put <br /> out the quotation mark ?
The browser shouldn't tell me that there is an error ? Or maybe it's uncorrectly set up, how can I know if it's correctly set up ?

Thanks

Comment: Hi, I'm glad it helps,
<br /> is an html tag and php can not interpret it if you put it out of ""

Answer (score 0):

In `secret.php`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
<?php
    if (!(isset($_POST['identifiant'])))
        echo "missing identifiant <br />";//changed
    if (isset($_POST['password']))
    {
        if (strcmp($_POST['password'], "coco") == 0)//changed
        {
            echo "You're authorised";
        }
        else//changed
        {
            echo "You're not authorised";
        }
    }
    else//changed
    {
        echo "missing password";
    }

?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why have I to change the line you mentionned ? thanks